# open multiple command windows for a python program

Tags: python, class, subprocess, subclass

I am trying to use two different processes side by side. But the problem is, right now, I can only switch between the process because each of them need to access the command prompt. What I am doing now is this:

```
Class A ()
   def foo1()

    def foo2()
       if x<10:
          exit process1

Class B ()
    def tuu1()

    def tuu2()
      if t>1:
          #do something
      else:
         A.foo2

def main()
    B.tuu2()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

So, basically what this logic does is that, it first runs the code of tuu2 for class B if the 'if t>1' condition is met, if it does'nt then it runs foo2 in Class A. Now when it runs foo2, it checks if the condition is met. If not, then it exits that process, which in turn starts the tuu2 of class B. This switching keep happening. What I want is that, not to exit foo2 but run foo2 and and tuu2 side by side when x<10 and just foo2 when x>10. I gave exit command only because, tuu2 runs only when I close whatever foo2 is doing. I hope you guys get what I mean.

EDIT-1

Is it possible to keep these two classes in separate python files and then write a python script to run the python file with class A and based on the value of x, run/exit program containing class B? Could anyone give me a sample code for this? I am newbie in python

Comment: Why couple the processes at all then? Wouldn't it be simpler and easier to just have a program that just starts both of them?

Comment: @AluanHaddad - I tried this using subprocesses/ parallel in VS 2017, but I could'nt get it to work. I split them into 2 .py files within the same project , with their own main functions but somehow, I couldn't them to run simultaneously